# Which data structure is suitable for task based system

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I wanna build a system that handles different task flows. What I mean, lets say I have three different types of flow. First flow contains 5 tasks in that order (a -> b -> c -> d -> e), second flow contains only 3 (a -> c -> g), third has 5 tasks to be completed (c -> a -> e -> g -> b). What data structure and algorithm is suitable for that scenario. I am thinking about a tree or a heap, but not sure which type of tree to use and which suits the best.

Answer (score 1):

I think that **Directed Acyclic Graph** is a good choice when you have tasks that can have dependencies on other tasks.
Each task is represented as a node, and the edges between nodes represent the flow or order in which tasks should be executed.
You can also use topological sorting to find a valid execution order for the tasks in each flow.